# Drupal, Joomla? Sponsor an Orphan

Tags: drupal, joomla, ubercart

I'm trying to find a relatively simple solution to deploy a website that allows someone to select an orphan and donate to that orphan. Each orphan would be a part of a orphanage...

I looked into Drupal and Ubercart but I didn't know enough about it at the time... felt kinda lost. Could someone point in the right direction? I'd like to use an open-source solution and as many pre-built modules as possible.

Comment: How is this going to work with a shopping cart? Can you explain it a bit? Are you going to create some products as donations?

Comment: Basically, each orphan can be sponsored... so I would imagine that it's kind of like a one-time buy and that orphan is then "out of stock" ... and of course, you can "buy" or sponsor as many orphans as you wish. So in that sense it's no different than a product. But the real point is to be able to have groups of orphans in an orphanage(s).

Comment: +1 for buying orphans via ubercart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in both ways.

I would do it with joomla though, in my opinion it is much more powerful than drupal, has a bigger community behind, and there are many free add-ons.

You can use [hikashop](http://www.hikashop.com/) as your shopping cart solution. It is is simple shopping cart solution that works very well with joomla.

I made [this e-shop](http://www.taschenundmehr.de) using joomla & hikashop recently.

Comment: Would it easily support what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: And "orphanages" can have a profile for them? It's not just a matter of grouping oprphans... each orphanage has a profile and information.

Comment: Yes, they can. In this case, orphanages will correspond to product categories and they can have a profile.

Answer (score 1):

Definately drupal - you are right when you say drupal is a bit much to take in, but with the right links, it's not so bad

http://diasporan.net/content/drupal-and-ngos-dango-modules-and-install-profile

That's everything you need, all packaged in a nice install profile. An install profile is like a C make file, it "compiles" drupal for you for a specific use case. Google "drupal install profiles" for more info (Hint, if you see pages explaining "Drush make" you're on the right track)

Comment: So this solution is meant for non-profit donations? You've used it before and it will accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm sorry but the best way would be simple and fast with [Prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com).

See you!

Note: I like Joomla! and Drupal but when it comes to ecommerce well... Lets hope that soon prestashop can be integrated with joomla and drupal.

Answer (score -1):

You can use drupal because its a very powerful cms.

- The best part is that manages the database very effectively so, if in future your data size        increases, then you don't have to worry about it.
- The installation is very easy. just visit drupal.org.
- The community of drupal is very supportive.